# Use URI Documentdb java spring boot in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a Spring Boot (Gradle) web application that runs in an ubuntu container.

I also have a method that opens a Mongodb connection in DocumentDB (AWS).

I need to export this URI (String) generated in the method so that it is possible to use the String URI in the application.yml file.

I thought about using environment variable, but I don't know if there is any better or easier way to do it.